# XSLT value-of not showing new paragraphs

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, saxon, apache-fop

I have problem of getting text from xml in original state.

When I use `<xsl:value-of select="desc" />` I get full text, but merged, without spaces between paragraphs.

I have data like this:

```
<desc><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat]]>
</desc>
```

And, as output I get this:

[image]

This is not good for me, because I want output text to be same as inside CDATA[], with blank lines between paragraphs.

I tried with using preserved spaces.

I'm using Saxon xslt processor

Comment: It has nothing to do with XSLT or Saxon, you need to generate the right attributes for your `fo` container elements, like `white-space-collapse="false"` and `white-space-treatment`, check your favourite XSL-FO reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve"` as your container element might suffice, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#linefeed-treatment.

Comment: I went in other direction while searching for solution. This solved my problem. Thanks.